# Google App Script add files to zip archive with zero compression

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way using google app script to add file to zip archive with zero compression? I only found class Utilities with method zip. However there is no parameters which allows to control compression levels or any other parameters of archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google App Script is a light-weight JavaScript based cloud scripting language to automate certain tasks and build web applications. Stressing on the word, "light-weight". Hence, it does not provide certain (or should say, all) functionalities as JavaScript does(or at least made possible through importing libraries) and unfortunately, ability to control compression ratio is one of them. However, you can file this as a Feature Request on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Ok, as I understand your answer it's not possible to create zip with different compression levels using app script. I need to pass zip file to another endpoint which can do this for me (for example some PHP script run on different server)?

Comment: Yeah, that could possibly work. But I've never tried to do anything like that myself with App Script. So you might have some work cut out for you there. :)